# Where does this tag come from : localization_country_currency_iso_code?

Tags: localization, shopify

I'm breaking my head analyzing the code of this website : https://divertioz.com/

In the footer, this code is generated :

```
<script id="localization_country_currency_iso_code" type="application/json">CAD</script>
```

I don't understand where this comes from as it breaks another script I use for US/canadien laws compliance.

Do you guys know where I can remove what generates that code please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what you need to do with it?

Comment: Hello Afazal, I need to remove it because it tempers an other script I use from the Illow App.
Illow app needs this script to run :
<script src="https://platform.illow.io/banner.js?siteId=fc6bb9bd-f760-4c1d-ba28-d2781019d9d9"></script>

But the console gives this error : 
Uncaught Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'C', "CAD" is not valid JSON

I know that is not an issue with Illow, I use it on so many websites.
Somehow the localization script changes the one from Illow.

Comment: check if there are any snippets around closing body tag